# How to concat two string literals at compile time in Zig?

Tags: string, compilation, string-concatenation, zig

How to do concat the following strings whose length are known at compile time in Zig?

```
const url = "https://github.com/{}/reponame";
const user = "Himujjal";
const final_url = url + user; // ??
```

Answer (score 18):

Array concatenation operator, for two comptime-known strings:

```rust
const final_url = "https://github.com/" ++ user ++ "/reponame";
```

std.fmt.comptimePrint for comptime-known strings and numbers and other formattable things:

```rust
const final_url = comptime std.fmt.comptimePrint("https://github.com/{s}/reponame", .{user});
```

Runtime, with allocation:

```rust
const final_url = try std.fmt.allocPrint(alloc, "https://github.com/{s}/reponame", .{user});
defer alloc.free(final_url);
```

Runtime, no allocation, with a comptime-known maximum length:

```rust
var buffer = [_]u8{undefined} ** 100;
const printed = try std.fmt.bufPrint(&buffer, "https://github.com/{s}/reponame", .{user});
```

Answer (score -1):

Its an easy thing to do. Lack of research produced this question. But for anyone wondering.

```
const final_url = "https://github.com/" ++ user ++ "/reponame";
```

For more information go through: [comptime in zig](https://ziglearn.org/chapter-1/#comptime).